# Leading zeros in an extracted Excel file from database using PEAR

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel, pear

In the admin section of my website there is a button that extracts an Excel file with data from my database. In reality, it is an Excel file that is created upon clicking the button using PEAR. I use an SQL query to get the information necessary from my SQL Server 2008 database.

One of the columns named 'number1' contains a number ranging from 1-9999. I have been looking for a way to have it put zeros in front of the numbers when it doesnt have 4 digits already, but I've had no luck until now. For example, if the number in the database is 12, I would like it to show as 0012 in my Excel sheet.

currently the code used is the following:

```
if ($j == 15){
$worksheet->write($variable1, $j , $variable2[$i][$j], $text222);
    }
where $variable1 = 0; $variable2 = ("my sql query")
```

Your help is appreciated.

EDIT: ANSWER(S)

```
$number = str_pad($value, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

OR

JAGAnalyst's answer, the one I actually used in my code.

Comment: Kindly format the datatype of column to text and then put 0012.

Comment: @Santosh not sure I understand. in my database the number is 12, when extracted into Excel it displays as 12. My goal is for it to be extracted and displayed in Excel as 0012, but to remain 12 in the database.

Comment: What i mean is before binding and exporting the data to excel change the datatype of excel column.

Comment: you want to change the data type in Excel, or just the format of the number as it's *displayed* in Excel?

Comment: @DavidZemens If I understand correctly, the format of the number as its displayed in Excel. Ultimately, all that matters is that all the numbers in that column appear as 0012, 0002, 0123, 1234 for example (when in my database they look like 12, 2, 123, 1234.

Comment: @Santosh Ok so once the format of that particular column is TEXT, what will alter the data to be displayed with leading zeros?

Comment: If you export to excel as TEXT then you can append `'00` (or as many zeros as may be needed).  You should use a leading apostrophe before the prefix zero(s).

Comment: @BillyCode First format the column as text and then put your data in that column. Then what ever you put in the column it will be displayed as it is. Yes for numbers with leading 0 if you put them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also edit your SQL query to return a four-character text string instead of a number, including the replacement function, i.e.

```
, CASE
WHEN Len(number1) = 1 THEN '000' + CAST(number1 AS VARCHAR(4))
WHEN Len(number1) = 2 THEN '00' + CAST(number1 AS VARCHAR(4))
WHEN Len(number1) = 3 THEN '0' + CAST(number1 AS VARCHAR(4))
ELSE CAST(number1 AS VARCHAR(4))
END AS NEW
```

This will actually alter the value that is extracted, rather than simply changing the format.